# Ethers.Js Error Uncaught SyntaxError

Tags: contract-development, javascript, ethers.js

I am trying to query the balance of an address of a contract I deployed to a localhost and keep running into this error. I know in Js once you declare a const variable you cannot re declare it but in this instance I was not able to define the variable balance so how would I go about getting to where I want i.e attempting to run  `const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(accounts[0].address)`  ?

Any help would be very appreciated :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well you are not passing a valid address, like said in the error! [0] is not an address.

`invalid addressor ENS name 'argument="name, value=[0], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT ...`

Maybe refer to an array that holds the address you're looking for ?
Also with ether.js you can define addresses on the local network like this:

```
const [owner, acc1, acc2, acc3] = await ethers.getSigners();
```

try changing it to:

```
let balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(acc1.address)
```

Comment: Thanks Torof. Do you have any advice on the Syntax error? Even once changed to `let balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(acc1.address)` as you suggested it still throws `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'balance' has already been declared`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work

```
await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
const signer = provider.getSigner()

let balance = await signer.getBalance();
balance = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)
```